# Why does the tensor product of rings correspond to the product of their spectra?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, tensor-products

I've been grinding away at understanding algebraic geometry on my own for a long while and things are starting to fall into place (a month before I start my first formal class in it). I answered some of my own questions in typing this up, but one thing is still nagging at me.

Start with the standard setup: let $k$ be algebraically closed and $A$ and $B$ f.g. $k$-algebras. Here is the knowledge we have coming in:

1. $\text{Spec}(A\times B)=\text{Spec}(A)\sqcup\text{Spec}(B)$
2. $A\otimes_k B$ is the quotient of $A\times B$ by the ideal generated by... (not gonna type out the whole definition of tensor)
3. For a ring $R$ with ideal $I$, the primes of $R/I$ are in correspondence with the ideals of $R$ containing $I$ (Correspondence theorem)

By the correspondence theorem it ought to be the case that $\text{Spec}(A\otimes_k B)$ be smaller than $\text{Spec}(A\times B)$, when in fact we have $\text{Spec}(A\otimes_k B)=\text{Spec}(A)\times\text{Spec}(B)$. I understand the categorical explanation in that $\text{Spec}$ is a contravariant functor and thus must send limits to colimits, but I don't understand why this disagrees with the intuition I have presented above. My best guess is that it has something to do with the tensor being in the category of $k$-algebras rather than commutative rings, but I'm failing at putting the pieces together specifically. Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The tensor product is the coproduct in the category of commutative $k$-algebras. As Spec is contravariant, it swaps products with coproducts (as in your 1.)

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I got that part. Didn't feel like being pedantic about it in this post, but I do understand the loss of accuracy as it stands. I'll update the post to  reflect this.

Comment: “contravariant functor and thus must preserve limits” – You certainly mean something like “must sent colimits to limits (if anything)”.

Comment: The tensor product is not a quotient of the usual product here. Just compare dimensions to see this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $C$ be a commutative ring and $A$ and $B$ be $C$-algebras. You have $C = k$, but I’ll be a bit more general.

As Tobias Kildetoft already said, $A \otimes_C B$ is *not* a quotient of $A × B$, but instead a quotient of the very much larger structure 
$$F(A×B) = \bigoplus_{(a,b) ∈ A × B} C·(a,b)$$
*as a $C$-module – not as a ring*. That module is *free $C$-module* on the set $A×B$ (hence the notation ‘$F(…)$’).

It then just turns out that the tensor product $A \otimes_C B$ of this structure can *also* be endowed with a ring structure, turning it to a $C$-algebra. The structure inherently comes from the universal property of tensor products as $C$-module, since multiplication in $C$-algebras are $C$-bilinear maps.

So you can’t easily compare the ideals of $A \otimes_C B$ with the ideals of $A × B$, that’s why your intuition fails.

Another thing: The high-level reason that $\operatorname{Spec} \colon \mathrm{C\,Rings}^\mathrm{op} → \mathrm{Schemes}$ turns the tensor product into the fibre product is *not* that it “is a contravariant functor”, but that it is, as such, a right-adjoint functor to the global section $Γ\colon \mathrm{Schemes} → \mathrm{C\,Rings}^\mathrm{op}$ and category theory tells us that right adjoints always preserve limits. Since the tensor product of $C$-algebras is the coproduct in $\mathrm{C\, Rings}$, it’s the product in the opposite category, so it is preserved by $\mathrm{Spec}$.

To help your intuition, maybe think of the very intuitive statements
$$\mathbb A^m_C × \mathbb A^n_C = \mathbb A^{m+n}_C \quad\text{and}\quad C[X_1,…,X_m] \otimes_C C[Y_1,…,Y_n] = C[X_1,…,X_m,Y_1,…Y_n].$$

Comment: Thank you, that cleared up a bunch of confusion for me. One thing that I've seen a lot and have been trying to understand is the whole global sections thing, which I'm assuming is the same as nlab's statements regarding modules being considered as generalized vector bundles. Do you have any intuition or resources relating to this that might help me understand what is being said there?

Comment: @hawkman561 They’re talking about coherent and quasi-coherent modules, I guess, which is covered in about resource on algebraic geometry out there, for example in the [stacks project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/) and in Ravi Vakil’s scriptum on algebraic geometry, [*The Rising Sea*](https://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/).

Comment: @hawkman561 Intuition: Each vector bundle $π \colon E → B$ with fiber $F$ defines a sheaf $\mathcal F_π$ on $B$, with its sections being the continuous sections of $π$; it’s stalks are vector spaces, namely exactly the fibers of $π$. As vector bundles are locally trivial, the sections locally on all small open $U ⊆ B$ look uniformly like the $C(U)$-module of continuous maps $U → F$. Quasi-coherent modules $\mathcal G$ on a ringed space $X$ are sheaves of modules, which, just as vector bundles, locally on all small open $U ⊆ X$ look like some $\mathcal O_X(U)$-module in a similarly uniform way.